# Endless loading/spinner on the checkout page on WooCommerce site

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

When the cart page proceeds to the checkout page, everything appears on the page, however, the payment section is "grayed" out and that area just "spins".it never allows me to proceed to the actual payment button.

**Things I’ve tried that didn’t work:**

1. Disabled all plugins (except woocommerce).
2. Changed theme to Default theme.
3. Checked Woocommerce>System Status. Then found MySQL version:         5.5.58 - We recommend a minimum MySQL version of 5.6. PHP version:      5.4.45 - We recommend a minimum PHP version of 5.6.
4. Checked items on this page: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/endless-
   loadingspinner-on-the-checkout-page/

How to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76429910/infinite-checkout-loading
i have these errors what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Ajax request failure. Check for CORS restrictions. Inspect the network tab for failed xhr requests. Also check the console for any errors, especially CORS ones.

Comment: I checked the network tab and also console error .there is no error i found.